# Loop Through Portion of XML String

Tags: python-3.x, xml, beautifulsoup, xml-parsing

I have data from a series of sensors that is delivered via an XML bytes formatted string. To format the XML string from the request, I am leveraging Python's BeautifulSoup with the lxml parser. The code to request this data is as follows:

```
import sys, os
import urllib.request as req
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

response = req.urlopen(""+apiaddr+"?username="+apiuser+"&password="+apipass+"&region=760")
ingest = response.read()
soup = bs(ingest, 'xml')
```

The raw bytes string of the request is as follows, please note that I've shortened the total data requested for brevity:

```
b'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><observation version="1.1.1"><instance><target><idType>stationId</idType><id>12418</id><name>Wx Sensor 1</name></target><resultOf codeSpace="ICE_SD" timestamp="2022-01-13 14:40:00"><value code="TS" no="1">0.0</value><value code="ST" no="1">4.0</value><value code="AL" no="1">2.0</value><value code="T" no="1">0.7</value><value code="TD" no="1">-6.1</value><value code="WL" no="1">0.01</value><value code="RH" no="1">60</value><value code="TD" no="2">-5.9</value><value code="IL" no="1">0.0</value><value code="SL" no="1">0.0</value><value code="FR" no="1">82.0</value><value code="T" no="2">0.7</value><value code="RH" no="2">60</value></resultOf></instance><instance><target><idType>stationId</idType><id>3171</id><name>Wx Sensor 2</name></target><resultOf codeSpace="ICE_SD" timestamp="2022-01-13 14:40:00"><value code="TS" no="1">-6.0</value><value code="ST" no="1">5.0</value><value code="AL" no="1">2.0</value><value code="TB" no="1">-4.5</value><value code="T" no="1">-6.2</value><value code="TD" no="1">-9.1</value><value code="WD" no="1">130</value><value code="WL" no="1">0.0</value><value code="RH" no="1">80</value><value code="WS" no="1">3.0</value><value code="WSM" no="1">3.8</value><value code="VI" no="1">2000</value><value code="IL" no="1">0.0</value><value code="SL" no="1">0.0</value><value code="WDM" no="1">143</value><value code="FR" no="1">81.0</value></resultOf></instance></observation>'
```

Using BeautifulSoup's Prettify function `print(soup.prettify())`, the more elegant view of this string is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<observation version="1.1.1">
 <instance>
  <target>
   <idType>
    stationId
   </idType>
   <id>
    12418
   </id>
   <name>
    Wx Sensor 1
   </name>
  </target>
  <resultOf codeSpace="ICE_SD" timestamp="2022-01-13 14:40:00">
   <value code="TS" no="1">
    0.0
   </value>
   <value code="ST" no="1">
    4.0
   </value>
   <value code="AL" no="1">
    2.0
   </value>
   <value code="T" no="1">
    0.7
   </value>
   <value code="TD" no="1">
    -6.1
   </value>
   <value code="WL" no="1">
    0.01
   </value>
   <value code="RH" no="1">
    60
   </value>
   <value code="TD" no="2">
    -5.9
   </value>
   <value code="IL" no="1">
    0.0
   </value>
   <value code="SL" no="1">
    0.0
   </value>
   <value code="FR" no="1">
    82.0
   </value>
   <value code="T" no="2">
    0.7
   </value>
   <value code="RH" no="2">
    60
   </value>
  </resultOf>
 </instance>
 <instance>
  <target>
   <idType>
    stationId
   </idType>
   <id>
    3171
   </id>
   <name>
    Wx Sensor 2
   </name>
  </target>
  <resultOf codeSpace="ICE_SD" timestamp="2022-01-13 14:40:00">
   <value code="TS" no="1">
    -6.0
   </value>
   <value code="ST" no="1">
    5.0
   </value>
   <value code="AL" no="1">
    2.0
   </value>
   <value code="TB" no="1">
    -4.5
   </value>
   <value code="T" no="1">
    -6.2
   </value>
   <value code="TD" no="1">
    -9.1
   </value>
   <value code="WD" no="1">
    130
   </value>
   <value code="WL" no="1">
    0.0
   </value>
   <value code="RH" no="1">
    80
   </value>
   <value code="WS" no="1">
    3.0
   </value>
   <value code="WSM" no="1">
    3.8
   </value>
   <value code="VI" no="1">
    2000
   </value>
   <value code="IL" no="1">
    0.0
   </value>
   <value code="SL" no="1">
    0.0
   </value>
   <value code="WDM" no="1">
    143
   </value>
   <value code="FR" no="1">
    81.0
   </value>
  </resultOf>
 </instance>
</observation>
```

My question is how can I loop through the **individual text entries** contained within  **underneath each sensor branch** (Wx Sensor 1, Wx Sensor 2, etc.) of the XML string? My first successful attempt was to use soup.find_all('value'), however I need to be able to map each of the text values to the sensor and compile them into an ordered dictionary.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the **exact** expected output given your sample xml?

Comment: Without knowing the output you seek we would just be guessing at a solution. I would probably start by doing a `for instance in find_all("instance")` then for each instance find the sensor id and values.